# Display flex Firefox - content not shrinking

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have a problem with simple flexbox layout in Firefox.
The parent div **.logos-grid** is not shrinking when you resize the browser window although in all other major browsers it does.

**The html:**

```
 <div class="grid">
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
      <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
 </div>
```

**The css:**

```
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.grid img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Demo on codepen: http://codepen.io/thomasoCZ/pen/VajQzJ?editors=1100

Please help :-)

Comment: is the number of images per row variable or is it always 5? (in other words: are you looking for a general-purpose solution or just for this specific scenario?)

Comment: Please see the answer given to the question in my previous comment. You'll need to add `min-width: 1px` to `.grid div`. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzMoqr?editors=1100

Comment: nice trick @HiddenHobbes , I'll remove my answer since your approach is simpler